# Gulp error: gulp.hasTask is not a function

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm getting the following when I run "gulp". Looks like I have a mixed of CLI and Local version, not really sure how to solve this problem.

```
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/apps/web-ui$ gulp -v
[22:44:23] CLI version 2.0.1
[22:44:23] Local version 4.0.0
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/apps/web-ui$
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/apps/web-ui$
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/apps/web-ui$ gulp
[22:44:28] Using gulpfile ~/workspace/apps/web-ui/gulpfile.js
[22:44:28] Starting 'default'...
[22:44:28] 'default' errored after 5.41 ms
[22:44:28] TypeError: gulp.hasTask is not a function
    at /home/cabox/workspace/apps/web-ui/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:23:22
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at verifyTaskSets (/home/cabox/workspace/apps/web-ui/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:17:11)
    at runSequence (/home/cabox/workspace/apps/web-ui/node_modules/run-sequence/index.js:130:2)
    at /home/cabox/workspace/apps/web-ui/gulpfile.js:187:5
    at taskWrapper (/home/cabox/workspace/apps/web-ui/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at asyncRunner (/home/cabox/workspace/apps/web-ui/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
cabox@box-codeanywhere:~/workspace/apps/web-ui$ ^C
```

Comment: Looks like people are having similar problem here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/4727

Answer (score 77):

Gulp v4 has breaking changes and that creates some problems with [run-sequence package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence).

As I do not have your gulpfile.js, all I can say upto this point is to try to use Gulp4's [gulp.series](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series) and [gulp.parallel](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel) with your gulp tasks, instead of run-sequence.

you may receive an error of the sort of like 'task1, 'task2' could not be completed', in the function of the task, accept the done callback and call the callback in your tasks at the end of the function

Example:

```js
gulp.task('task1', gulp.series('task1-1', function (done) {
   // task 1 code here
    done();
}));

gulp.task('task2', gulp.series('task2-1', function (done) {
   // task 2 code here
    done();
}));

// Similarly Tasks 3 and 4 Code here

gulp.task('main', gulp.series('task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4', function (done) {
    done();
}));
```

Answer (score 35):

[Saurabh Pati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50132567/1743124) is *the* answer. BTW a quick workaround would be to replace [run-sqeuence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) package with the [gulp4-run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp4-run-sequence) package.

If your project has Gulp installed locally, remove local version of Gulp:

```
yarn remove gulp
```

Then open the `package.json` and replace `"run-sequence": "^0.3.6",` with

```
"gulp4-run-sequence": "^1.0.0",
```

Now run

```
yarn install
```

In your `Gulpfile.js`, replace `runSequence = require('run-sequence'),` with

```
runSequence = require('gulp4-run-sequence'),
```

And, you are done. :)

Comment: 2020 follow up, this works great coming from a basic 4.0.2 Gulp install but still running the previous 'run-sequence'.

Comment: Thank you, this feels a much better answer than downgrading!

Comment: This is the best and only working answer for me... Thanks a lot Mayeenul!

Comment: For me having problems with the olda run-sequence , this answer helped me!

Answer (score 28):

All that matters is the Local Version. Since gulp 4.0.0 introduced breaking changes, you can simply do what I did --- explicitly set the local package back to a working version:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp@3.9.1
```

This has bit me a couple times recently and I'll be coming back here again, I'm sure.

**Note: The dependencies of gulp 3.9.1 have many security vulnerabilities.  You should not do this.**

Comment: I believe that gulp versions less than 4 have vulnerabilities, that's why I upgraded. Is it something to be worries about.

Comment: Installing gulp 3.9.1 instead of 4.0.0 fixed the `TypeError: gulp.hasTask is not a function` error for me, which was causing rev-manifest.json to be missing, but it does show 12 vulnerabilities (1 low, 4 moderate, 6 high, 1 critical).

Comment: sticking to an old version forever is not a viable strategy

Comment: Perhaps not! Yet it is a tactic that is working for me. ;)

Comment: Working, but insecure: 5 security vulnerabilities in the dependencies of 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and couldn't install gulp 3.9.1 version. After instaling, was any way 4.0.0. Installing the same version for -g and --save dev - solves the issues with hasTask and gives 3.9.1 version for CLI and local. Don't fix the vulnerabilities. It turns gulp local to 4.0.0. 
So just install `npm i gulp @3.9.1 -g` and `npm i gulp @3.9.1 --save-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error..From my research i discovered is due to gulp version 4.0. Therefore if you have gulp4.0  and above this solution is for you..Install a later version like
npm install --save-dev gulp@3.9.1, then i deleted my node_modules folder and ran 
npm install again from the command prompt..and everything works perfect now..thanks to @tptompkins.

Comment: Please post a link where it states that the function is deprectated or not working anymore in gulp 4.0 - in order to inform the poster accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

After reading all the suggestions here, what worked for me was running 'npm install --save-dev gulp@3.9.1'. I didnt have to delete my node_modules folder or having to specify '-g' or '--save-dev'.